# How can I make new line or break in array?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a popover and I want to have break between each items 
in content- data.

```
 %i.fa.fa-folder.item{"data-content" => "#{folder.doc.map{ |file_id| File.find(file_id).name}.join{"<br />"}.html_safe}",rel: "popover", title: "title:"}
```

I have added "\n" to the the join but its not working. Do you have any idea where should I put the "\n" in the code?

Comment: Can you put more code of your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a newline will not work, as HTML will ignore any whitespace/newlines to best format string as contiguous as possible. So you have to use `<br/>` to add an explicit line-break in HTML. However, now, in rails for safety any string will be html-escaped *unless* you explicitly instruct rails to *not* do that.

So in your case you want to build the list of files, claim it is safe, and then set as content. Something like

```
- file_list = folder.doc.map{|file_id| File.find(file_id).name}.join('<br/>').html_safe
%i.fa.fa-folder.item{data: {content: file_list, html: "true", rel: "popover", title: "title:"}
```

Secondly, because you are using bootstrap to render the popover, you will also have to instruct the bootstrap popover that the `data-content` is interpreted as html and should not be escaped (by setting the `data-html` attribute).

Comment: It is printing ou the <br /> as well.;-(

Comment: I simplified it a little, and I assume you are using bootstrap, then you still need to specify the `data-html` option as well as otherwise bootstrap will escape the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is not rendered as a newline in HTML. Use `<br />` tag instead:

```
 #{folder.doc.map{ |file_id| File.find(file_id).name}.join("<br />").html_safe}",rel: "popover", title: "title:
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. it is adding <br  /> to end of my items.like this : file1<br />file2 <br />

Comment: I believe this is because you are `.html_safe`ing the string.  If you "view source" you'll see that instead of `<br />` you have `&lt;br /&gt;`

Comment: @mrzasa , like this? <&lt;br /&gt;>

Comment: @elisabaker you meant to tag me, not @mrzasa :-)  I'm saying that .html_safe is converting the `<` and `>` to *html safe* versions of those characters, `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which tell the browser to *print out a less than and greater than sign, respectively*.  You need to add the `<\br>` *after* you `.html_safe` the file name and this should work

Comment: @LeroyStav oooh, sorry .that's right. Thanks for helping.:-)

Answer (score 0):

If this is being displayed in a browser then a `\n` will only put a newline character *in the code*.  The HTML newline *tag* is `<br />`.  However, without knowing more about the general context you are using this in it is hard to give you good advice.

Normally if I am making a list of things then I would wrap the whole list in, say, a `<ul>` tag, and each list item in an `<li>`... Or possibly each one should be wrapped in a `<div>`.

The thing about HTML, like most programming languages, is that there are many ways to do an arbitrary thing, but there are better ones or worse ones depending on the bigger picture

Comment: In my case where exactly should I put the <ul> . I updated the question

Comment: Again, this is entirely up to you.  If what you want is, indeed, an li, ultimately you want the html to look like `<ul><li>FILENAME</li><li>FILENAME</li></ul>`  Having zero idea of what language/framework/whatever you are using to generate the html I can't tell you how this is actually done.

Comment: @Leory Stav:yes, I want to have <ul><li>FILENAME</li><li>FILENAME</li></ul>. I am working with ruby on rails. the format that I am using is called haml.

Comment: You misunderstood.... Had I recognized the framework I would have been able to tell you, but because I don't, you telling me what it is still doesn't help me help you, sorry

Comment: Not sure why @LeroyStav added this answer, if anything it only shows their confusion. If you do not understand the question, you should have added a comment instead.

Comment: I understood entirely and answered his answer completely.  Not only that, I also commented on another answer that gave the same answer as me with less details as to why replacing `\n` with `<br />` didn't work for him.  I will now respond there *again* to help him further.  It is not *my* confusion that is the problem, rather it is @elisabaker 's inexperience that is the problem, here, as she doesn't understand how the framework she is using outputs html.  This is *not* a ror issue, nor a javascript one, but an HTML problem to which I *have answered the question to*.  Thanks for judging!

Answer (score 0):

For that case I would recommend using a [helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

Helper

```
module MyHelper
  def render_data_content(folder)
    folder.doc.map do |file_id| 
      File.find(file_id).name
    end.join('<br/>').html_safe
  end
end
```

View

```
%i.fa.fa-folder.item{"data-content" => render_data_content(folder) ,rel: "popover", title: "title:"}
```

Comment: @elisabaker can you put more of your view? And you have to include your helper on your controller like: helper  :my

Comment: @ Javier Menéndez Rizo : Thank you so much for your help.  html: "true" worked for me.